# How to take multiple lines of input

Tags: java

If I copy and paste into a program It only takes the first line for instance I copy a few blocks from Microsoft Excel and Paste it pastes the codes like this:

```
72LYY-785B9-0WQD9
88CXK-4E8BB-TA2GD
JLEIZ-0KYKP-PY2E4
LV5TL-A6CLB-P59GX
```

My program only takes `72LYY-785B9-0WQD9`, but I want the scanner to take all until it is empty.

I am using

```
String userData = takeInput.nextLine();
```

I put it into a String and then turn it into an array of chars.
Any help?

Comment: Are you looping using `while (takeInput.hasNextLine()) {...}`? Please show the surrounding code too.

Comment: It is in a loop. But it asks for input over and over again instead of taking the rest

Comment: Do you want to read *all* the lines as one single String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try any other approach?

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
while (stdin.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(stdin.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: This worked! Sorry, I hit the up arrow but don't have enough reputation. I don't want it to print out but I am going to change it to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Great! You don't need to hit the up arrow button, just mark as acceptable answer, it helps some other person to go straight to the solution.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere? But now I've ran into a new error. I tried debugging but the while loop ends the program. I followed it through the debugger and it for some reason it takes away my ability to hit next when the `while (stdin.hasNext()) {` should come up as false..

Comment: The stdin.hasNext() will be false when it reads all the lines that you inputted. Do you want to keep reading the user input? If so, I'll edit the code in my answer. By the way, there's a check mark under the up and down arrows.

Comment: stdin.hasNext isn't showing as false.. It keeps taking input. I paste the codes but it keeps accepting more and more. If I keep pressing enter it keeps accepting inputs and looping. Sorry, I have never used BufferedInputStream.. I'm in school studying CS 2 but this is personal not part of my HW lol